# How to count foreign keys in different columns from the same table?

Tags: mysql

I'm developing this system that I have one table for the teams and one for the superstars. In the teams table I have this 4 columns that have foreign keys which references to the superstars table.

[Table Teams Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD9KS.png)

My objective is to know who was the most picked superstar on the teams. Currently I'm using 4 codes and sum the results manually.

Code that I'm using:

```
SELECT superstars.name,COUNT(superstar01) FROM smackdown_teams JOIN superstars on smackdown_teams.superstar01 = superstars.id GROUP by superstar01 Order by COUNT(superstar01) desc;
SELECT superstars.name,COUNT(superstar02) FROM smackdown_teams JOIN superstars on smackdown_teams.superstar02 = superstars.id GROUP by superstar02 Order by COUNT(superstar02) desc;
SELECT superstars.name,COUNT(superstar03) FROM smackdown_teams JOIN superstars on smackdown_teams.superstar03 = superstars.id GROUP by superstar03 Order by COUNT(superstar03) desc;
SELECT superstars.name,COUNT(superstar04) FROM smackdown_teams JOIN superstars on smackdown_teams.superstar04 = superstars.id GROUP by superstar04 Order by COUNT(superstar04) desc;
```

Any suggestions of how can I know who is the most picked Id ?

Answer (score 1):

You can union the result and find max of the result.

```
select max(superstar)
(SELECT superstars.name,COUNT(superstar01) as superstar FROM smackdown_teams JOIN superstars on smackdown_teams.superstar01 = superstars.id GROUP by superstar01 Order by COUNT(superstar01) desc
UNION
SELECT superstars.name,COUNT(superstar02) as superstar FROM smackdown_teams JOIN superstars on smackdown_teams.superstar02 = superstars.id GROUP by superstar02 Order by COUNT(superstar02) desc)
```